# Problems with deploying apache kylin

Tags: kylin

I am new to apache-kylin,and currently I am deploying kylin on Vmware Worksation.I met some problems when it started.Then I check the log file,here is part of what it shows:

```
   Error creating bean with name 'aclService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableExistsException: kylin_metadata_acl
```

detail info
[problems with deploying apache kylin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4I14.png)
Who can help?Thanks

Comment: You need to past full stack trace. This error may caused by others.

Comment: Thanks,I changed the version of hbase and kylin, it worked.